# Substitute character " in Excel Substitute Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

how do I substitute character " for : using excel substitute formula?

Cell A1:"

Formula I am trying to do:

=SUBSTITUTE(A1,""",":")

It comes with a mistake because " cannot be inside the " ".

How could this be corrected?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to precede a double quote with a double quote, so you need four double quotes: One to start the string, one to quote the quote, then the quote and then the closing quote for the string. Counting skills help.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"""","--")
```

[image]